# maven se encarga de instalar todas las dependencias?

Tags: maven, spring-boot

estoy haciendo unas pruebas de crud con spring-boot, pero en la dependencia de

ojdbc queda en rojo, creo que no esta siendo importada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trate de usar este:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.noraui</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

fijese en el grupoId -> `com.github.noraui`

Comment: entonces las dependencias deben ser instaladas automaticamente? y si en caso quiero abrir un proyecto de spring-boot hecho en eclipse puedo abrirlo en intelij idea?

Comment: probe y sigue saliendo rojo

Comment: no entendi bien sus comentario: puede usar `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, ... > Build Tools > Maven > Importing`  y marcar `Import Maven projects automatically`, tambien existe un boton por la UI que al pasarlo por encima pone "Reimport All Maven Projects" https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/maven-importing.html. Sobre lo de eclipse puede mirar esto -> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/eclipse.html no le puedo decir sobre Eclipse y Intellij Idea. Por otro lado cuando tenga las dep. en su OS puede marcar "Work Offline" si lo desea en el menu de Maven visto antes.Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que tengo entendido, es por que Oracle pide usuario y clave cuando quieres descargar sus productos.

Tuvimos un problema parecido, lo solucionamos así.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>
```